# Which key is denoted by a ^ on a Macbook?

Tags: mac, keyboard

I have switched to Mac recently from Windows so I apologise if this question seems silly to experienced users. In various keyboard shortcuts, the `^` key is mentioned. Which key are we talking about here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is <kbd>^ CTRL</kbd> key (or <kbd>Control</kbd> on some keyboards).

Here'e more info on Apple [website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).

> Mac menus and keyboards often use symbols for certain keys, including the modifier keys:
>
> - Command ⌘
> - Shift ⇧
> - Option ⌥
> - Control ⌃
> - Caps Lock ⇪
> - Fn